# Videos Not auto playing on mobiles and tablets

Tags: android, ios, twitter-bootstrap, video, autoplay

I have created a website, first proper website, with bootstrap. Almost got the website to where i want it to be. I have a video on the main page (.mp4 1080p), which i have set to loop and auto play. Works perfect on laptops, but cant seem to get it to work on properly on phones and tablets.

Tried it on an Ipad and and Iphone, and the auto play doesnt work, i have to click the play button. I have looked into this and it is supposed to work on anything above IOS10, which they both were, and doesnt have any soundtrack, which is also the case. On my android phone it just shows up as a black box and i cant play or pause or anything.

Any help would be appreciated. the website is actually live www.dtlaerialservices.co.uk, i can place the code here if required.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div align="center" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
<video autoplay loop class="embed-responsive-item">
<source src="videos/loop.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: I've checked, The youtube videos are playing in my Samsung Note 2.

Comment: Autoplay is usually disabled on Mobiles to prevent users running up large data usage bills.

Comment: I agree with @Mick. **Think** of your mobile end-users and their internet speed or data allowance before shoving a huge **186 megabyte** 1080p video down their little phone screens. They'll never return. A front page video should be a few megs (teaser). Maybe have a second link/option to watch that demo video in full length. Provide various picture size choices if possible (upload multiple copies)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common problem, and it's an encoding issue. You will need to encode your video using **H264** as the video codec, and **AAC** as the audio codec.

When you use H264 as your video codec, you will also need to choose a profile. Higher profiles require more CPU power to decode and are able to generate better looking videos at same bitrate. You should always choose the best profile your target devices support.

For example, the max supported profile for Desktop browsers, iPhone 4S+, iPad 2+, Android 4.x+ tablets, Xbox 360, Playstation 3 is **High profile**.

Most devices also have a maximum resolution and bitrate they can handle. That is usually expressed in as a H.264 level.

You can re-encode your video using the **ffmpeg** utility.

I personally use a website called [CloudConvert](https://cloudconvert.com/mp4-to-mp4), you just have to set the conversion options to:

- Video Codec: H264
- Audio Codec: AAC
- Leave the other options at their default values

There is also good information [here](https://www.virag.si/2012/01/web-video-encoding-tutorial-with-ffmpeg-0-9/).

Comment: I have encoded it H264 and AAC in a lower quality, and hidden the large video on xs and sm devices (bootstrap) on my devices it still shows a black screen, on the laptop i can see the videos changeover when i resize the window. any ideas what im doing wrong?

Comment: I have converted the mp4 video with a custom profile called iPhone6S but it still does not show up. I tried H264 and AAC, same result. Desktop is OK but mobile phone not.